# MongoJS: MongoError: failed to connect to server with correct credentials

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using this plugin: https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs .

I used to log in via Node.js without credential successfuly:

```
var db = mongojs("dbname", []);
```

Later on I have shut down the Mongo and restarted it but this time it was with the command: mongod --auth.
I already had a user roled to the admin database.

Then I have tried to log in again via Node.js, but this time with the user credentials:

```
var db = mongojs("username:password@mydomain.com:8080/dbname", []);
```

And I have also tried with a different syntax:

```
var db = mongojs("username:password@mydomain.com:271017/dbname", []);
```

And I have also tried:

```
var db = mongojs("username:password@dbname", []);
```

As you can see, I have tried lots of syntax methods but nothing did the trick.

I have to mention, that the credentials I used are just fine, I have just logged successfuly via Robo3T (Robomongo) and Mongo Compass with the same details.

I have also tried to revoke the user from admin and put it specifically on dbname but it did not work.

**My question:**

What is the correct way in order to login with credentials from Node.js?
Please provide a solution based on the library I used and provided above from GitHub.
(If you have a better and more efficient way I will be glad to hear in addition).

**A semi question popped up:**

I have noticed that when i oblige Mongo to ask for a user in order to continue work with the database, I receive an error in Terminal / SSH:

```
Error: not authorized on <dbname> to execute command { usersInfo: 1.0 } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1363
```

The above error appears when trying to do the same thing via Terminal on my own Mac and either via SSH on my remote VPS.

I put the details how correct as I can, I hope it is clear enough!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

I have just needed this:

```
var db = mongojs("mongodb://MYUSERNAME:MYPASSWORD@localhost:27017/DBNAME", []);
```

Just replace the capital letters with the credentials.

Really, I have searched for it for 3 hours or more.